# find files if directory name exists within directory in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read some file which is inside some specific directory like.
I am trying to use python2.7+ version. Here is my requirements like:

Find directory starts with B1234 (here 1234 is nr) inside output folder
if directory exists then goto directories starting with only TEST_
read only file endswith YYYY.txt
but that can reside inside subdirectory (name is not important here)
I am trying to make following code working but in vain

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('output'):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith('test') and file.endswith('_YYYY.txt'):
            try:
                f =  open(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root,file)) , 'r')
            except:
                print 'oops'
```

Problem is here I can find all desired files but also from unwanted directories..
i would like to use like that

```
for dir in dirList:
if dir startswith(B1234)
for testdir in os.listdir(dir)
if dir.startswiht(TEST_)
goto dir
search for file
```

Any help will be appreciable..please askif you need more info:

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the change here :

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('output'):
    for dir in dirs:
        if dir.startswith('B1234') is False:
            continue
        for r, drs, fls in os.walk(dir):
            # now write your code here
```

Comment: hello "r, drs, fls in os.walk(dir)" will not work because os.walk will retrieve files, directory in parrallel. i need to check directory first then if matches needs to extract only files remembering which directory curretnly i am in

Comment: You can also try using os.listdir() method in the innermost for loop.

Comment: how to use and how can you resoltve and return the path?

Comment: To resolve path issues, check this module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html, specially os.path.join(). And os.listdir() is simple, just pass the directory name as the parameter, it will return the list of files and directories, you then match if the files fit in your pattern.